# Update ServiceWorker without page reload on Safari

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I want my PWA to periodically update itself while it is running, not waiting for the user to refresh the page (e.g. on iOS 12 it is actually quite hard to trigger page reload of a PWA).

I know there is [ServiceWorkerRegistration.update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) method, but it's not supported by Safari.

**So, are there any workarounds to get my ServiceWorker to self-update without page reload on iOS?**

Additional information:

Currently I periodically poll `version.json` file in which I put current app's version, compare it, and force a page reload. It works fine, but it requires two page reload to get the new version (this + after the activated event to load the new app's assets).

Here's my current solution, if you need more context: https://github.com/dimaip/calendar/blob/master/app/serviceWorker.js#L31

Comment: Would falling back on `location.reload()` work?

Comment: @KenKinder hey, yes, that's basically what I had in mind if I got a definitive NO to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ServiceWorkerRegistration.update()` is supported by all browsers that support service workers, and should accomplish what you want.

If you wanted to confirm for yourself that it's actually supported in Safari, try running

```
reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready
reg.update()
```

in Safari's JS console, with the Network panel open. You should see a request made for your service worker after you run that.

Comment: Are you sure? Because this page provides a different information, it doesn't seem to be supported by the iOS Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update

Comment: I can't think of any reason why desktop Safari would support it but mobile Safari wouldn't. It's not a new part of the service worker specification. But you can test it out yourself to confirm. I just tried it on the XCode iOS Simulator, for instance, and it worked in Safari there.

Comment: Actually you are right, I tested on iOS13 and it seems to work just fine! I was confused by the MDN docs and didn't bother to check myself. I've sent them a note.